# put form elements all form elements into specific object array

Tags: javascript

**UPDATED**
How would I get all form elements from a form and format them in an object to match the output of the following object(using only javascript)?

```
var feature = dojo.byId('searchString').value;

         var OBJECTID= dojo.byId('OBJECTID').value;
```

**This is the format I need:**

```
var updates = {attributes:{
          OBJECTID:OBJECTID,
          SubWS:feature
        }};
```

**form elements:**

```
<input type="text" id="OBJECTID" value="" />
<input type="text" id="searchString" value="" />
```

output: [image]

This is my working script, but the output does not match the above "updates". The final version will loop through many more form fields that will sometimes be updated, so i don't want to hardcode the attributes.

```
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      console.log("inputs array", inputs);
var params = {attributes:{}};
for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    var curr = inputs[i];
    if(curr.getAttribute('type')==='text'){
        params[curr.getAttribute('name')] = curr.value;
    }
}
```

this is what it looks like on my actual form.  As you can see the object is slightly different.
[image]

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: where would I change name != id?

Comment: @StormWater I think CBroe is trying to tell you that `name` and `id` are not the same thing. in your example of form elements you have given them all an id, yet in your javascript you are grabbing the name attribute

Comment: CBroe/Mark:  That is correct, I was basing the loop on grabbing all the name (i.e. text) from the form.  Aside from hard coding a get ID for each element, i don't know how to grab each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i've understood you correctly then you need to change the follow line

```
params.attributes[curr.getAttribute('name')] = curr.value;
```

By adding `.attributes` you should match the structure you are after.